# Divide and Conquer strategy to determine if more than 1/3 same element in list

Tags: python, algorithm, divide-and-conquer

I am working an a divide and conquer algorithm to determine if more than 1/3 elements in list are the same.
For example: [1,2,3,4] No, all element are unique.
[1,1,2,4,5] Yes, 2 of them are the same.

Without sorting, is there a divide and conquer strategy ?
I get stucked on how to divide...

```
def is_valid(ids): 
    n = len(ids) 
    is_valid_recur(ids, n n-1)

def is_valid_recur(ids, l, r):
    m = (l + h) // 2
    return ....  is_valid_recur(ids, l, m) ...is_valid_recur(ids, m+1, r):
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: What about the naive approach: counting until any count exceeds `len(ids)//2`?

Comment: What about this algorithm: http://users.eecs.northwestern.edu/~dda902/336/hw4-sol.pdf for finding the majority element?

Comment: Is this a homework ?

Comment: What if two items each are more than 1/3 of the list: [1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3]?

Comment: @user448810 It should return true as long as one element is more than 1/3

Comment: @YvesDaoust No, it's a practice question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a rough draft I experimented with for fun. It looks like the divide and conquer may reduce the number of candidate frequency checks but I'm not sure (see the last example, where only 0 is checked against the full list).

If we divide the list in three, the smallest frequency a valid candidate can have is 1/3 of each part. This narrows our list of candidates for searching in other parts. Let `f(A, l, r)` represent candidates that could have a frequency of 1/3 or more in their parent group. Then:

```py
from math import ceil

def f(A, l, r):
  length = r - l + 1

  if length <= 3:
    candidates = A[l:r+1]
    print "l, r, candidates: %s, %s, %s\n" % (l, r, candidates)
    return candidates

  i = 0
  j = 0
  third = length // 3
  lg_third = int(ceil(length / float(3)))
  sm_third = lg_third // 3

  if length % 3 == 1:
    i, j = l + third, l + 2 * third
  elif length % 3 == 2:
    i, j = l + third, l + 2 * third + 1
  else:
    i, j = l + third - 1, l + 2 * third - 1

  left_candidates = f(A, l, i)
  middle_candidates = f(A, i + 1, j)
  right_candidates = f(A, j + 1, r)
  print "length: %s, sm_third: %s, lg_third: %s" % (length, sm_third, lg_third)
  print "Candidate parts: %s, %s, %s" % (left_candidates, middle_candidates, right_candidates)
  left_part = A[l:i+1]
  middle_part = A[i+1:j+1]
  right_part = A[j+1:r+1]
  candidates = []
  seen = []

  for e in left_candidates:
    if e in seen or e in candidates:
      continue
    seen.append(e)
    count = left_part.count(e)
    if count >= lg_third:
      candidates.append(e)
    else:
      middle_part_count = middle_part.count(e)
      print "Left: counting %s in middle: %s" % (e, middle_part_count)
      if middle_part_count >= sm_third:
        count = count + middle_part_count
      right_part_count = right_part.count(e)
      print "Left: counting %s in right: %s" % (e, right_part_count)
      if right_part_count >= sm_third:
        count = count + right_part_count
      if count >= lg_third:
        candidates.append(e)

  seen = []
  for e in middle_candidates:
    if e in seen or e in candidates:
      continue
    seen.append(e)
    count = middle_part.count(e)
    if count >= lg_third:
      candidates.append(e)
    else:
      left_part_count = left_part.count(e)
      print "Middle: counting %s in left: %s" % (e, left_part_count)
      if left_part_count >= sm_third:
        count = count + left_part_count
      right_part_count = right_part.count(e)
      print "Middle: counting %s in right: %s" % (e, right_part_count)
      if right_part_count >= sm_third:
        count = count + right_part_count
      if count >= lg_third:
        candidates.append(e)

  seen = []
  for e in right_candidates:
    if e in seen or e in candidates:
      continue
    seen.append(e)
    count = right_part.count(e)
    if count >= lg_third:
      candidates.append(e)
    else:
      left_part_count = left_part.count(e)
      print "Right: counting %s in left: %s" % (e, left_part_count)
      if left_part_count >= sm_third:
        count = count + left_part_count
      middle_part_count = middle_part.count(e)
      print "Right: counting %s in middle: %s" % (e, middle_part_count)
      if middle_part_count >= sm_third:
        count = count + middle_part_count
      if count >= lg_third:
        candidates.append(e)
  print "l, r, candidates: %s, %s, %s\n" % (l, r, candidates)
  return candidates


#A = [1, 1, 2, 4, 5]
#A = [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3]
#A = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3]
A = [2, 2, 1, 3, 3, 1, 4, 4, 1]
#A = [x for x in range(1, 13)] + [0] * 6
print f(A, 0, len(A) - 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Binary Search Tree (BST).
1.  Create BST maintaining key count at each node
2.  Traverse tree to find maximum key count using divide and conquer
3.  Test if max count > n/3 
With data in BST, divide and conquer is simple since we just
have to determine if the left, current, or right branch has the highest repeat count.

```
# A utility function to create a new BST node  
class newNode:  
    # Constructor to create a new node  
    def __init__(self, data):  
        self.key = data 
        self.count = 1
        self.left = None
        self.right = None

# A utility function to insert a new node  
# with given key in BST  
def insert(node, key): 
    # If the tree is empty, return a new node  
    if node == None: 
        k = newNode(key) 
        return k 

    # If key already exists in BST, increment 
    # count and return  
    if key == node.key: 
        (node.count) += 1
        return node 

    # Otherwise, recur down the tree  
    if key < node.key:  
        node.left = insert(node.left, key)  
    else: 
        node.right = insert(node.right, key) 

    # return the (unchanged) node pointer  
    return node 

# Finds the node with the highest count in a binary search tree
def MaxCount(node):
  if node == None:
    return 0, None
  else:
    left = MaxCount(node.left)
    right = MaxCount(node.right)
    current = node.count, node

    return max([left, right, current], key=lambda x: x[0])

def generateBST(a):
  root = None
  for x in a:
    root = insert(root, x)

  return root

# Driver Code 
if __name__ == '__main__': 
    a = [1, 2, 3, 1, 1]
    root = generateBST(a)
    cnt, node = MaxCount(root)
    if cnt >= (len(a) // 3):
      print(node.key)  # Prints 1
    else:
      print(None)
```

A **non-divide and conquer** technique for n/3 which has O(n) time from https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/n3-repeated-number-array-o1-space/:

```
# Python 3 program to find if  
# any element appears more than 
# n/3. 
import sys 

def appearsNBy3(arr, n): 

    count1 = 0
    count2 = 0
    first = sys.maxsize 
    second = sys.maxsize 

    for i in range(0, n):  

        # if this element is 
        # previously seen,  
        # increment count1. 
        if (first == arr[i]): 
            count1 += 1

        # if this element is 
        # previously seen,  
        # increment count2. 
        elif (second == arr[i]): 
            count2 += 1

        elif (count1 == 0): 
            count1 += 1
            first = arr[i] 

        elif (count2 == 0): 
            count2 += 1
            second = arr[i] 


        # if current element is  
        # different from both 
        # the previously seen  
        # variables, decrement 
        # both the counts. 
        else: 
            count1 -= 1
            count2 -= 1



    count1 = 0
    count2 = 0

    # Again traverse the array 
    # and find the actual counts. 
    for i in range(0, n):  
        if (arr[i] == first): 
            count1 += 1

        elif (arr[i] == second): 
            count2 += 1


    if (count1 > n / 3): 
        return first 

    if (count2 > n / 3): 
        return second 

    return -1

# Driver code 
arr = [1, 2, 3, 1, 1 ] 
n = len(arr)  
print(appearsNBy3(arr, n))
```

Comment: Thanks! I also want the algorithm to determine if the list has more than 1/3 elements in common. I am not sure how to modify the algorithm..

Comment: @chen didn't see how either so I modified my post using a different algorithm.

Comment: Thanks.. but, this algorithm seems not divide and conquer. I am trying to modify your previous algorithm..

Comment: @chen I made a mod to Majority Algorithm to produce one for n/3 rather than n/2.  Check recent post.

Comment: @DarrylG try it for [2, 2, 1, 3,3,1,4,4,1]

Comment: @shukiavraham Thanks for the test.  Remove that non-working code.

Comment: @DarrylG Thans for all of your help. I am working on your first version of the code. I tried [1,2,1,3,4], then it returns None, but should be 1...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57789350/divide-and-conquer-find-the-majority-of-element-in-array I opened another post for the bug.. @DarrylG

Comment: @chen Made a comment to your post.  The algorithm finds the majority item not the most frequent item.

Comment: @DarrylG Yes... you are right.. I just realized that. I only want to find the most frequent item. It doesn't have to be at least half.

Comment: A simple majority divide-and-conquer cannot work for n/3. You might have 3 As, 4 Bs, and 3 Cs in order (using letters instead of numbers). Splitting in half should find A as majority element in first half and C in second half, but the right answer is B. For n/2 that cannot occur since the overall majority element must be a majority element in at least one of the divisions.

Comment: @HansOlsson yes, you are correct, so modified post accordingly. Thanks

Comment: @HansOlsson modified post to use a binary search tree.